# Add size in Gallery Settings in Media Library

Tags: gallery, media-library

I would like to add the size in the Gallery Settings in the Add Media.

I know to add the in the front-end by editing the media.php.

However, when I added the the lines in gallery.dev.js, they don't seem to work.

Here are the lines I had added in gallery.dev.js

Added size

```
 setup : function()
      var t = this, a, ed = t.editor, g, columns,size, link, order, orderby;
```

Added galsize in the same setup : function (approx line 128)

```
 if ( getUserSetting('galsize') ) t.I('size').value = getUserSetting('galsize');
```

Added in setup : function (approx line 141)

```
 size = a.match(/order='"['"]/i);
```

Added in setup : function (approx line 150 )

```
 if ( size && size[1] ) t.I('size').value = size[1];
```

Added size in update : function (approx line 170)

```
   all = all.replace(/\s*(order|link|columns|size|orderby)=['"]([^'"]+)['"]/gi, '');
```

Added in getsettings : function

```
    if ( I('size').value != 'medium' ) {
            s += ' size="'+I('size').value+'"';
            setUserSetting('galsize', I('size').value);
        }
```

Comment: You should **never ever** edit core files. There is almost certainly some hook you should be able to use to accomplish what you want (which, unfortunately, I'm not sure I'm understanding).

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Basically in the Gallery Tab in Media Uploader, I would like to display the 4 media size part of the Gallery Settings

Answer (score 5):

first +1 for the first commenter .
**NEVER CHANGE CORE FILES.**

this function will do the trick for your media upload :

```
function dl_custom_image_sizes_add_settings($sizes) {
       unset( $sizes['thumbnail']); //comment to remove size if needed
       //unset( $sizes['medium']);// uncomment to remove size if needed
       //unset( $sizes['large']);// uncomment to restore size if needed
       unset( $sizes['full'] ); // comment to remove size if needed
       $mynewimgsizes = array(
              "your-custom-size_name-1" => __( "Name_to_display1" ),
              "your-custom-size_name-2" => __( "Name_to_display2" ),
              "your-custom-size_name-3" => __( "Name_to_display3" )
       );
       $newimgsizes = array_merge($sizes, $mynewimgsizes);
       return $newimgsizes;
}
add_filter('image_size_names_choose', 'dl_custom_image_sizes_add_settings');
```

of course , this will work only if you define them first like so :

```
/*
Post Thumbnails Support
*/
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post' ) ); // Add it for posts
add_image_size( 'your-custom-size_name-1', 220, 100, true ); // Permalink thumbnail size
add_image_size( 'your-custom-size_name-2', 50, 50, true ); // example home  thumbnail size
add_image_size( 'your-custom-size_name-3', 470, 350, false ); //  slider size
```

otherwise it will show greyed out buttons..

Comment: Hi should this be in the theme function.php? Would this add the image size only to the Gallery tab in the Media Uploader?

Comment: yes.. put in functions.php

Comment: Hi, I added them into function.php, but I don't see any option in my Gallery Settings under Gallery tab

Comment: they will show in the add media screen, like you initially asked .

Comment: hi krembo, thanks for the quick response. I want them to appear under the Gallery Settings, right above the Gallery Column.

Comment: the code I gave you will add the custom sizes for each picture , just before "insert to post" in the image upload . Now I do not understand anymore where exactly you want it ..