# Add option to "Gallery Settings" section

Tags: gallery, options

I want to add a option to the "Gallery settings" (when you insert a gallery into a post).

I once found some code on how to do this, but unfortunately I can't find it anymore.
I can't even remenber if it was a hook, but I think it was some hackish stuff ;-)

Thx

Comment: How about [those questions/answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=gallery+settings)?

Comment: Nope...the first question is the only one that is looking for the same thing. But the answer to it `There is no way to alter the gallery settings.` is just wrong. I have done it, but dumped the code =(

Comment: [And this one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39004/add-size-in-gallery-settings-in-media-library) is also one of the results. Sorry, but you're not specific enough. Anyway: Dig in core, get the `~/wp-admin/*.php` file for that request and search for `apply_filters/do_action`.

Comment: this only sets image sizes. I need another option. As I said, it was a hackish solution, there is no hook as I can see. The option was added via JS, but I can't get it to work that option integrates in the shortcode when inserted into the editor.

Comment: "Sorry, but you're not specific enough.". Please rework your question and be more specific/add more details. Thanks.

Comment: Above answer doesn't work in WP 3.6 - try this instead: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90114/enhance-media-manager-for-gallery/90504#90504

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the hint with the multiple galleries plugin from Niall Campbell and thanks to this question [How to Add a Custom Colum on Thickbox Media Gallery Tab?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53803/how-to-add-a-custom-colum-on-thickbox-media-gallery-tab) (where I got the hook `admin_head-media-upload-popup` from), I was able to complete the task.

I've added an option to add a `style` attribute to the gallery shortcode.

[image: option to select the style of the gallery]

Here is the complete code:

```
add_action( 'admin_head-media-upload-popup', 'wpse_53803_script_enqueuer' );

function wpse_53803_script_enqueuer() 
{
    if( $_GET['tab'] == 'gallery' ) 
    {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

            // append the table row
            $('#gallery-settings table#basic tbody').append('<tr><th scope="row" class="label"><label><span class="alignleft">Style:</span></label></th><td class="field"><select id="style" name="style"><option value="standard">Standard</option><option value="slideshow">Slideshow</option></select></td></tr>');

            // set our vars
            var $style = '', $is_update = false;

            // Select parent editor, read existing gallery data 
            w = wpgallery.getWin();
            editor = w.tinymce.EditorManager.activeEditor;

            if (editor !== null) {
                gal = editor.selection.getNode();

                if (editor.dom.hasClass(gal, 'wpGallery')) {
                    $style = editor.dom.getAttrib(gal, 'title').match(/style=['"]([^'"]+)['"]/i);
                    var $is_update = true;
                    if ($style != null) {
                        $style = $style[1];
                        $('table#basic #style').find('option[value="' + $style + '"]').attr('selected','selected');
                    }
                } else {
                    $('#insert-gallery').show();
                    $('#update-gallery').hide();
                }
            }

            // remove standard onmousedown action
            $('#insert-gallery').attr('onmousedown', '');

            // Insert or update the actual shortcode
            $('#update-gallery, #insert-gallery, #save-all').mousedown(function() {
                var $styleAdd = '';
                if (editor !== null)
                    var orig_gallery = editor.dom.decode(editor.dom.getAttrib(gal, 'title'));
                else
                    var orig_gallery = '';

                // Check which which style is selected
                if($('table#basic #style').val() != 'standard') {
                    $styleAdd = ' style="slideshow"';
                }

                if ($(this).attr('id') == 'insert-gallery') {
                    w.send_to_editor('[gallery' + wpgallery.getSettings() + $styleAdd + ']');
                }

                // Update existing shortcode
                if ($is_update) {
                    if ($styleAdd != '' && orig_gallery.indexOf(' style=') == -1)
                        editor.dom.setAttrib(gal, 'title', orig_gallery + $styleAdd);
                    else if (orig_gallery.indexOf(' style=') != -1)
                        editor.dom.setAttrib(gal, 'title', orig_gallery.replace(' style="slideshow"', $styleAdd));
                    else
                        editor.dom.setAttrib(gal, 'title', orig_gallery.replace(' style="slideshow"', ''));
                }
            });

        });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

It adds `style="slideshow"` if the slideshow style is selected, otherwise it doesn't add anything. And it recognizes the set style if you update the gallery, so that the right option is selected.

Thank you!

Comment: Does it still work in 4.9?

Answer (score 4):

hmmm check out the code to Mutliple Galleries plugin, it uses a javascript workaround due to the absence of a wordpress hook for the media_upload_gallery_form function (in wp-admin/includes). It then outputs a modified gallery shortcode to the editor (with some extra attributes).

If you're adding in additional attributes that aren't covered by the gallery shortcode, you'll need to write your own function for it, but there's alot of information available to do that out there so I won't go into that.

Comment: Welcome to our site. Please add the solution to your answer, so it can stand for itself. Thanks.