# Any way to add custom options to Gallery Settings?

Tags: custom-field, gallery

Now that Wordpress has updated to version 3.5, the media gallery has been overhauled and [this custom options solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65857/add-option-to-gallery-settings-section) doesn't appear to work anymore. I'd like to add a couple of fields to the gallery, so that a client doesn't have to manually add these fields to the gallery shortcode.

Does anyone know how to add custom fields with the new 3.5 gallery?

Comment: Apparently, we'll have to wait for 3.5.1 or .2 ... The [file that renders](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/media-template.php) the attachment details in the Add Media screen doesn't seem to have any hook for this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the nightly builds of the Advanced Custom Fields plugin can (mostly) handle this now, so you could try installing that. Details on [this support issue](http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/discussion/comment/13287#Comment_13287).

I can't update my copy of it to test right now but this is what it would look like in the admin:

[image]

Comment: As of today the "Location" is called "Forms->Attachment" and it only adds the field to individual media items, not to galleries as the question asks.