# Which file renders the "Edit Gallery" Settings page?

Tags: shortcode, gallery, core

I was looking for a tutorial on adding options to the "Edit Gallery" page. In the hopes of adding some GUI inputs that would result in the generated [gallery] short-code having custom attributes.

I found [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76026/any-way-to-add-custom-options-to-gallery-settings). I was hoping that taking a look at how the page and options are rendered, and were the request "insert gallery" is sent would help me understand the issue.

So again the questions are :

1) Where in the WordPress core can I see how the "Edit Gallery" page and its settings are rendered?

2) What file / function handles the "insert gallery" request ?

I created a separate questions so someone could get some easy points : )

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsing through the code at http://core.trac.wordpress.org/, it appears that the file you're looking for is `/wp-includes/media.php`.  I wouldn't recommend editing core files, though; any updates you make would be clobbered in the next upgrade.

Comment: Thank you. I don't want to edit core files. I just want to see how it works.