# Custom wordpress gallery option

Tags: gallery

I would like to add custom option to default wordpress gallery tab.
I need something simple just a drop down to add offered style, 
this would add predefined class to gallery on client side and on edit view in admin part.

[image]

Is there a way to do this without hacking wordpress code.

I saw a post here: [Add option to "Gallery Settings" section](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65857/add-option-to-gallery-settings-section) which show how to do what I wan't but, I tried it and it doesn't work, I guess that's because the example is for ~3.5 version, and I am using 4.1.1 How can I do this with my current version.

Comment: what option do you want to add exactly? what was the full code you have tried?

Answer (score 7):

WordPress doesn't make it very easy to modify aspects of the [gallery shortcode](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/media.php#L939). Some attributions:

- Thanks to user [peterbra](https://wordpress.org/support/profile/peterbra) for really putting the whole thing together [a year ago](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-add-fields-to-gallery-settings?replies=5#post-5000775).
- Thanks to user [birgire](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/26350/birgire) for coming up with [a solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/208207/7355) as far as adding the attribute in a meaningful way.

The other option besides birgires ( as far as I know ) is to pretty much rebuild the shortcode by copying existing code the cores [media.php file](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/media.php#L939) which is a pain.

---

Some things to note on the initial `additional_gallery_settings()` function, from [peterbra](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-add-fields-to-gallery-settings?replies=5#post-5000775):

- The `tmpl-` prefix is required.
- Your field should have a `data-setting` attribute

Just throw the following code into your `functions.php` file:

```php
/**
 * Set up the new field in the media module.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function additional_gallery_settings() {
  ?>

    <script type="text/html" id="tmpl-custom-gallery-setting">
        <span>Style</span>
        <select data-setting="style">
            <option value="default-style">Default Style</option>
            <option value="custom-style">Custom Style</option>
            <option value="ie7-style">IE7 Style</option>
        </select>
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
            _.extend( wp.media.gallery.defaults, {
                style: 'default-style'
            } );

            wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery = wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery.extend( {
                template: function( view ) {
                    return wp.media.template( 'gallery-settings' )( view )
                         + wp.media.template( 'custom-gallery-setting' )( view );
                }
            } );
        } );
    </script>

  <?php
}
add_action( 'print_media_templates', 'additional_gallery_settings' );

/**
 * HTML Wrapper - Support for a custom class attribute in the native gallery shortcode
 *
 * @param string $html
 * @param array $attr
 * @param int $instance
 *
 * @return $html
 */
function customize_gallery_abit( $html, $attr, $instance ) {

    if( isset( $attr['style'] ) && $style = $attr['style'] ) {
        // Unset attribute to avoid infinite recursive loops
        unset( $attr['style'] ); 

        // Our custom HTML wrapper
        $html = sprintf( 
            '<div class="wpse-gallery-wrapper-%s">%s</div>',
            esc_attr( $style ),
            gallery_shortcode( $attr )
        );
    }

    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'post_gallery', 'customize_gallery_abit', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: looks like "wp.media.gallery.defaults" is now "wp.media.galleryDefaults"