# How to specify a class added to my gallery

Tags: css, gallery, post-class

I would like to add a class to my gallery short code, this is how I have added my class:

```
[gallery class="small" columns="2" ids="350,349,302,305"].
```

Now the confusion comes in, I am not sure how to specify the class in my css.

I have tried:

```
.small .gallery 
.gallery-1 img 
.gallery
```

Answer (score 11):

Here are three methods

### Approach #1

It's common to wrap the output with custom HTML. We can do that by using the `post_gallery` filter and the `gallery_shortcode()` callback:

```
/**
 * HTML Wrapper - Support for a custom class attribute in the native gallery shortcode
 */
add_filter( 'post_gallery', function( $html, $attr, $instance )
{
    if( isset( $attr['class'] ) && $class = $attr['class'] )
    {
        // Unset attribute to avoid infinite recursive loops
        unset( $attr['class'] ); 

        // Our custom HTML wrapper
        $html = sprintf( 
            '<div class="wpse-gallery-wrapper-%s">%s</div>',
            esc_attr( $class ),
            gallery_shortcode( $attr )
        );
    }

    return $html;

}, 10 ,3 );
```

**Example:**

If we set the `class` attribute to the native gallery shortcode as *small*:

```
[gallery class="small" columns="2" ids="350,349,302,305"].
```

then the HTML output will be:

```
<div class="wpse-gallery-wrapper-small">
    <!-- The default gallery HTML output comes here -->
</div>
```

where we can now target it with the `.wpse-gallery-wrapper-small` class selector.

### Approach #2

Another approach would be to modify the current class attribute with help of some string replacements. Let's use the `post_gallery` and the `gallery_style` filters together:

```
/**
 * HTML Replacement - Support for a custom class attribute in the native gallery shortcode
 */
add_filter( 'post_gallery', function( $html, $attr, $instance )
{
    add_filter( 'gallery_style', function( $html ) use ( $attr )
    {
        if( isset( $attr['class'] ) && $class = $attr['class'] )
        {
            unset( $attr['class'] );

            // Modify & replace the current class attribute
            $html = str_replace( 
                "class='gallery ",
                sprintf( 
                    "class='gallery wpse-gallery-%s ",
                    esc_attr( $class )
                ),
                $html
            );
        }
        return $html;
    } );

    return $html;
}, 10 ,3 );
```

**Example:**

Using this shortcode:

```
[gallery class="small" columns="2" ids="350,349,302,305"].
```

will give the following HTML output:

```
<style>...</style>

<div id="gallery-1" class='gallery wpse-gallery-small ... '> ... </div>
```

where the class selector is `.wpse-gallery-wrapper-small`.

### Approach #3

Use the default id selector for the gallery instance.

```
id='gallery-1'
```

or the default class selectors:

```
class='gallery galleryid-123 gallery-columns-3 gallery-size-thumbnail'
```

where `123` is the current post id.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, my counting is not always perfect ;-)  @PieterGoosen

Comment: Just caught it because I read your post the first time before the final edit ;-)

Comment: ... or maybe  1+1+1 = 2, for *small values* of 1 ;-) @PieterGoosen

Comment: Mind you, you are the mathematician (*thanks for the auto correct feature on the spelling here*), so anything goes, hahaha. ;-)

Comment: hehe or a math clown ;-)  yes I  really like the auto correction feature in the comments.  @PieterGoosen

Comment: WP no longer uses just `.gallery` :( but abuses users with `wp-block-gallery`, `blocks-gallery-grid`, etc...